# Custom directives not loading templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-template

I have created a custom directive to display data retrieved from the controller. The element is displaying in the HTML script however, no data is being presented in the custom directive. My question is how to get my custom directive to display the incoming data from the controller.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>dashful</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" media="screen" title="no title">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-resource/1.6.1/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="config/config.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/index.js"></script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" src="directives/news.js"></script>
  <base href="/" target="_blank" />
</head>

<body ng-app='app'>
  <header>
    <nav class="nav-bar">
      <h1 id="brand">dashful</h1>
      <i id="settings-icon" class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main class="dashboard">
    <section class="dashboard" ui-view></section>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer dashboard-footer">Copyright &copy; 739688, MMXVII</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
```

controllers/index.js

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('IndexCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get('/widgets')
  .then(function(widgets){
    console.log(widgets);
    $scope.widgets = widgets.data;
    return widgets.data;
  })
});
```

config/config.js

```
angular.module('app')
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
  $stateProvider
  .state('dashboard', {
    url         : '/',
    templateUrl : 'views/index.html',
    controller  : 'IndexCtrl'
  });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

directives/news.js

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('newsWidget', [function () {
  return {
    restrict    : 'E',
    templateUrl : 'partials/news.html',
    controller  : 'IndexCtrl',
    scope       : {
      widget  : '='
    }
  }
}]);
```

views/index.html

```html
<section class="widgets">
  <article class="widget" ng-repeat="widget in widgets">
    <news-widget widget="widget"></news-widget>
  </article>
</section>
```

partials/news.html

```html
<span>{{widget}}</span>
```

Comment: In your `views/index.html` try printing the `{{widget}}` and check whether it is updating

Comment: Yes it updates and gives me the current object but I'd like to have this inside custom directives as there I will have many widgets such as news, sports etc.

Comment: Then you can use $scope.$watch to watch for changes

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. What changes exactly am I looking for? Thank you.

Comment: I assumed that the two-way scope binding would automatically do this.

Comment: It does Indeed, however if you use directive you need to track the changes using '$scope.$watch'

Answer (score 0):

In your `newsWidget` directive you are again setting `app` module so replace

`angular.module('app',[])` with
 `angular.module('app')`

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('newsWidget', [function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'partials/news.html',
            controller: 'IndexCtrl',
            scope: {
                widget: '='
            }
        }
    }]);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gangadharjannu/4u8xyrqb/)

Comment: My custom directive still isn't receiving the object data from the controller.

Comment: @BM4 can you quickly create a minimal working copy of your issue?

Comment: MY project was done in a modular way so I'm not sure how to correctly fix it together in the fiddle but I still attempted.

Comment: Still unresolved. The custom directive just doesn't seem to be communicating with the controller.

Comment: For me it is working check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gangadharjannu/4u8xyrqb/) in answer

Comment: Yes, the fiddle works. Could you please tell me what the $timeout service is for and if I need it?

Comment: I just used it for demonstration purpose. Instead of $http I've used $timeout to replicate the changes in value. You don't need that